# Login page that retrieves a token

Tags: dart, flutter

I have an app that requires users to log in. I have the website for the login page and everything.

So I've been using the "flutter_webview_plugin", "openid_client" "flutter_appauth" packages. At the moment I have a webview that opens the login page. So the home page is just a button that routes to a class called "LoginScreen()", which then shows the web page. That's what you see in the code. I am fairly new to flutter and programming as a whole, so please explain as if I have no idea what I'm doing.

Another note is that I am unsure where to apply the logic for the authentication and token retrieval. i.e. in the home page or login page where the webview is

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter_appauth/flutter_appauth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {

  final flutterWebviewPlugin = new FlutterWebviewPlugin();

  StreamSubscription _onDestroy;
  StreamSubscription<String> _onUrlChanged;
  StreamSubscription<WebViewStateChanged> _onStateChanged;

  String token;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Every listener should be canceled, the same should be done with this stream.
    _onDestroy.cancel();
    _onUrlChanged.cancel();
    _onStateChanged.cancel();
    flutterWebviewPlugin.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    //flutterWebviewPlugin.close();

    // Add a listener to on destroy WebView, so you can make came actions.
    _onDestroy = flutterWebviewPlugin.onDestroy.listen((_) {
      print("destroy");
    });

    _onStateChanged =
        flutterWebviewPlugin.onStateChanged.listen((WebViewStateChanged state) {
          print("onStateChanged: ${state.type} ${state.url}");
        });

    // Add a listener to on url changed
    _onUrlChanged = flutterWebviewPlugin.onUrlChanged.listen((String url) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          print("URL changed: $url");
        //flutterWebviewPlugin.close();

        });
      }
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String url = "http://login/page";
    return WebviewScaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Login"),
      ),
      url: url,
      withZoom: false,

    );
  }
}
```

The webview works, but I have no idea how implement the logic

Comment: Can you mention for what you want help?

Comment: I need the login page to authorize a user and then retrieve the/a token

Answer (score 0):

You're going about this the complete wrong way. Flutter is meant to provide an easier to build native experience. You're using a more advance technology than native programming and making it depend on a lesser technology which is wrapping webviews in a native app. I would suggest the following. If you can implement them.

- Expose your API for your login publicly so that you can access it from the mobile app directly.
- Build your own login screen on Flutter and don't wrap a website using Flutter.
- Once your API is exposed, return your token as a normal json object and use it in the application as you wish.

If you can't change the api and really want to wrap your application (which I don't recommend) then don't use Flutter. [Flutter's webview](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/webview_flutter) is very limited (It's still in developers preview as it depends on adding Native views into the Element tree, which is an upcoming feature). Use a technology that's catered towards wrapping websites and that provides built in support. If you're new to programming this will be very confusing so use something that's catered towards what you want to do.

I'd recommend looking at the following technologies:

- [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) (which is going out of fashion Very quick)
- [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/) More popular and is kind of still growing amongst the native hybrids even though it's completely web based.

I know it's not the answer you were probably looking for but based on your question you're going to have a much harder time with solving this problem. Please try and follow the first points I laid out, your development experience will be much better and your solution will benefit as well in terms of simplicity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll speak to the people at my company and see if we can do it this way